# Creating 64 bit application with VC++ 2010

Tags: windows, visual-c++, 64-bit, visual-c++-2010

I am trying to create a 64 bit application that will run on Windows Server (I am testing with Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bit).  My development environment is Visual C++ 2010 on Windows 7 64 bit. Right now I am experimenting with a very simple "hello world" console application.  In the properties of my test app, the platform is "Active (x64)". This compiles and links fine, and on my Win7 development machine, works fine.  When the program is running, I can go to Task Manager and see that it is a 64 bit application.

However when I run that executable on Windows 2008, I immediately get "the application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)".  I saw some advice to run Dependency Checker.  The result of this is "Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module. Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.".  All of the dependent modules (e.g. kernel32.dll, msvcr100.dll) have the CPU type set to x86.
Only my main exe has the CPU set to x64.  Is that the problem?  Why does this run on my Win7 system but not Server 2008, and what can I do to correct the problem?

Comment: You can't load 32-bit DLLs into a 64-bit process. All the DLLs you use in a x64 EXE must be x64.

Comment: RIght, but how do I specify in Visual C that all the dependencies should be the 64 bit versions?  That is not something that I set up in any way - I would have thought VC should do that automatically when I say I want to create a  64 bit app?

Comment: Are you building with Visual Studio build or using the command-line? Are you using VS 2010 SP1?  Also, why not use a newer, supported version of Visual C++?

Comment: Using the Visual Studio UI but eventually will need command line.  Right, I am using Visual Studio 2010 SP1.  I am trying to avoid the inevitable pain of migration all my other applications to a new version of VS, but I will if I have to.  What exactly do I get with respect to creating 64 bit apps?  Right now, when I try to create a new project, the only options are win 32 console or win 32 project (or empty project). I tried creating a win 32 console app then changed the platform to x64.  Is that the problem?  Could I do what I want by creating an empty project?

Comment: You create a Win32 project which only has a Win32/x86 Platform. You then use the Configuration Manager to add a New Platform and select AMD64 or x64. BTW, newer versions of Visual C++ have templates which are already populated with x86 and x64.

Comment: That is what I did.  Presumably that is why the created .exe works as a 64 bit program on my Windows 7 machine.  But why doesn't it work on Windows 2008?